# Publish new version of Google Sheets Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I have published a Google Sheets Add-on for internal use. It works. But I can't seem to publish a new version. I'm following this:

https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/manage-addons

Given Google's announcement that they're retiring Chrome Store listings post Jan 28, I've been focusing on deploying to G Suite Marketplace. The steps I've taken are:

- Update apps script
- Create new version (File > Manage Versions ... > Save new version)
- Edit G Suite Marketplace listing to use new version (per step 4 under "Update your editor add-on" in above page)

No amount of waiting or refreshing seems to cause the latest deployed code to be visible when I invoke the Add-on in a sample Sheets document.

Comment: Have you tried submitting your issue in the [Chrome Web Store Support page](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support/?hl=en)?

Comment: Thanks. I have not. But I don't *think* this is a Chrome Store concern. My understanding is that Google is deprecating Chrome Store listings for Add-ons, which is the only reason I'm trying to publish this to G Suite Marketplace. Publishing to the Chrome Store was comparatively simple.

Comment: Have you seen [Update published add-on code](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/manage-addons#update_published_add-on_code)? FWIW, the Google docs references for: 1) [Publishing an editor add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publish-addons) - which specifically mentions the Chrome Web Store closure/migration; 2) [Chrome Web Store migration](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/cws-migration).

Comment: Thanks, @Tedinoz yes. The "Update published add-on code" section seems promising, but no matter how tightly I follow the steps, the deployed Add-on still reflects old code. Item 5 reads "update the versioned deployment", and links to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments#editing_a_versioned_deployment Perhaps this is the part I'm misunderstanding? I click Publish > "Deploy from manifest" and create a new "Deployment" using my latest script version (the same one used by the marketplace listing), but when i run the add-on, I still see the older deployment.

Comment: So, statement of the bleeding obvious, your add-on _does_ include a manifest?

Comment: It does, albeit a very simple manifest. Literally just:

{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}

In case it's not clear, I have successfully deploy v7 of the add-on before through G Suite marketplace. It's visible for everyone on our domain. I'm writing this SO post because I can't seem to activate v8 or v9... But if there's something I can add to the manifest, please advise. I had thought the manifest did not need attention given that I have been able to deploy once.

Comment: Interesting comments on  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54407954]. Not sure why (https://superuser.com/) would be any better, but _who knows_... I left a note 
(probably not kosher, but how else does one do it) for Kos to see if he can throw any light on your problem.

Comment: @Tedinoz I have same problem as OP described, but in my case all users have installed add-on from Web Store, so new version applies to all of them. I hope they will fix deployment to G Guite Marketplace.

Answer (score 4):

In your Google Cloud Platform project, go to the Configuration panel of the G Suite Marketplace SDK. Scroll down until you find "Editor Add-on extensions". You should see two text inputs – one with your Apps Script ID, and another below it, which is the version of your script used for the deployment.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way we can do this as part of CI/CD Pipeline?