# Sheets add-on Chrome Web Store to G suite migration: Change visibility?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, chrome-web-store

I have a sheets add-on currently accessible only to a specified group of users through the Chrome Web Store.

Google recently let it be known that they are moving all add-ons from the Chrome Web Store to the G suite marketplace and posted directions to do this [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/cws-migration).

All the settings from the Chrome Web Store listing were imported with the exception of the 'visibility' settings below. It was defaulted to 'public' without the ability to change to private or select a Google Group as the Chrome Web Store allows.

Is there anyway to change the visibility to either private or restrict access to a google group or has this functionality been eliminated in the migration from the Chrome Web Store to G suite marketplace?

Thank you for any help.

Chrome Web Store visibility options:
[CWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gmq5W.png)
G Suite Marketplace visibility options:
[GrayedGSUITE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HIfr.png)

Comment: You might get more traction researching over at https://superuser.com/ or asking Google. You should definitely show your research.

Comment: Your add-on probably was published public at some time previously, now in G Suite Marketplace you cannot make it private, but you can "unlist" it on the next screen of settings.

Comment: @Kos On a tangent, do you have any thoughts on a somewhat different though related subject on (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54356083/)?