# How to debug Google Sheets Extension Plugin: No Setup option appearing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-marketplace, google-apps-script-addon, clasp

We have a Google Sheets extension deployed as a plugin. And it works. Here is a picture of the Config screen I'm talking about (to disambiguate between Chrome plugins, etc):

[image: Screenshot of our Deployment Screen]

The version we have deployed that works is version 12. However, when we try and deploy a new version it doesn't work. Specifically:

- We use clasp to create a new version
- We use the above screen and keep the script ID the same but change the version to the new version
- We click Save
- We go to a Spreadsheet and the Plugin shows up as an Add On as it did before, but there is no menu other than "Help".
- The logs show that onOpen was called, but there are no logs associated with it (even when we put Logger.log messages in onOpen:

[image: Screenshot of our logs screen]

This happens even when we use Clasp to pull down version 12 (The version that does work) and deploy it as a new version.

Does anybody have any idea how to even go about debugging this? It seems like the bits don't matter b/c we are deploying bits we are certain work. But it also seems like the only configuration is the version field of the Configuration screen.

Comment: Have you tried with [StackDriver logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#stackdriver_logging) using `console.log`?

Comment: Yes. StackDriver says there are no logs which makes us think the code is never executing.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the issue. If you are a GSuite user, recommend you to head over their [support team](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your published add-on to use the version 12, on the G Suite Marketplace SDK Settings page for your addon,

1. on the version field write `12`
2. click the **Save changes** button at the bottom of the page
3. If your spreadsheet was opened, reload the tab

Related

- [Publish new version of Google Sheets Add-on](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54356083/1595451)